# Get queue name from message

Tags: mule

I have used mule 3.

In my flow I will need add choice by using queue name.

How can I get queue name from message in xml file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual JMS queue or topic is available in the JMS Header called `JMSDestination`. You can extract this as the named message property from mule called `JMSDestination`.

The resulting XML might look like this (depending on the way things are set up on your end):

```
  <choice>
    <when expression="message.inboundProperties['JMSDestination'].endsWith('.A')">
      <!-- do something -->
    </when>
    <when expression="message.inboundProperties['JMSDestination'].endsWith('.B')">
      <! -- do something else -->
    </when>
    <otherwise>
      <! -- do the default -->
    </otherwise>
  </choice>
```