# How to get name of different Queues in MULE.

Tags: mule-studio

Currently, I'm using composite source to work with multiple queue in MULE. I need to get the queue name in the java transformer next to the composite source by converting object to string. 
Basically, how can I get names of different Queues. Any Help?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740670/get-queue-name-from-message

Comment: This is not working. I am getting null value here